# Should /etc/default/grub be an empty file? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm attempting to make a change to Grub on 22.04, so per the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2), I edit /etc/default/grub. However, this file is empty, and the change I make does not have the intended effect. From everything I've read, it should contain some stuff.

For reference, I'm attempting to enable unsupported SFP transceivers with the ixgbe driver using this string:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”ixgbe.allow_unsupported_sfp=1″

per the instructions [here](https://cesbo.com/en/latest/linux/unsupported-sfp)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by (re?)-installing Grub: 'sudo apt install grub2'. After I did this, the /etc/default/grub file was populated with a basic configuration, albeit not as extensive as suggested by Rinzwind.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The file by default has this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I verified that mine is empty. This is a fresh install of 22.04. How should I proceed?

Comment: edit yours with this and then follow the remark at the top of this file

Comment: Is it possible I didn't have grub installed? This is on a 'minimal' server install. I issued 'apt install grub2': The following additional packages will be installed:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin
Suggested packages:
  desktop-base
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-efi-amd64

Comment: not sure; we generally do have grub installed but it is possible to not have grub :)